# Pivotal Cloud Foundry - Working with Service Registry Locally

Tags: java, netflix-eureka, cloud-foundry

In my Pivotal Cloud Foundry development environment, I have a Service Registry created and a bunch of services bound.

Seeing as there is no easy way to debug services that are actually running on PCF, I want to bind my local services to the Service Registry I have created my PCF dev.  When I have asked how to do this, I have been told that this is basically impossible to do.

So my question is, how do I go about debugging my services if I can't connect onto my Service Registry in Dev?  The two possibilities I can think of are:

1. Deploy a Eureka server locally, as well as all the dependent services I am going to be connecting to.  If I have a lot of services I am connecting to, this is going to be a major headache.
2. While testing, I can change my code and hard-code in a service endpoint of a dev service instead of relying on the Service Registry and Ribbon.  This will work, but is very dangerous because I may accidentally check in some of this code.

Is there another possibility that I am missing?  Are there any easier/safer approaches?

Answer (score 0):

For debugging, I found using [Spring Sleuth Zipkin](https://spring.io/blog/2016/02/15/distributed-tracing-with-spring-cloud-sleuth-and-spring-cloud-zipkin) can be very valuable.

And I hope you are using [Spring Registration and Discovery](https://spring.io/guides/gs/service-registration-and-discovery/).

Spring takes care of lot of internals stuff for Netflix Eureka. 
I suggest, you give it a try, it will make debugging and maintenance a whole lot easier.